# Configuring use of AppIdentityService on development server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authorization

I have an app that currently uses the `com.google.appendinge.api.appidentity.AppIdentityService` to facilitate authentication & authorization for using the same app's [ie. same account] spreadsheet data via the `SpreadsheetService` API. Works great in production mode deployed to the GAE environment. But for obvious reasons, it doesn't work (authentication error, no surprise there) running in my development appengine environment.

My question is: is it possible & 'supported' to configure one's local development server to use the necessary key & certificate info to enable the AppIdentityService to work as intended?

I read the article https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/authenticate-google-app-engine-app and I understand it to suggest that it is possible but I be mis-understanding key points & would appreciate any feedback pro & con regarding this.

In a perfect world, I'd like my testing env to mimic the production mode as closely as possible. I am also considering using the 'normal' oauth2 web app authentication in my testing env but would prefer sticking with using AppIdentityService if at all possible.

I suspect the `com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.dev.LocalAppIdentityService` class in the `appengine-api-stubs.jar` is the intended technique but has anyone else also used this to provide `AppIdentityService` authentication within a development server? My initial assumption is that replacing the class `com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.IAppIdentityServiceFactoryProvider` found in com.google.appengine.spi.FactoryProvider to use my own factory class using the above LocalAppIdentityService class. Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Using GAE SDK 1.8.8 for Java.

Comment: I don't think it makes a lot of sense to use AppIdentity: the trust anchor for AppIdentity is App Engine in Prod. In Dev environment, you need a new trust anchor anyway (i.e. a service account). You might program a new AppIdentityService, but why bother? You need a new user and therefore different code anyway in Dev. 
I use factories that generate DriveService and SpreadsheetService, using AppIdentity (in Prod) or service account (in Dev). AppIdentity and the service account get different permissions in Drive, the service account can only access test data.

Answer (score 1):

When running under the local dev server, the GAE Java App Identity API calls the [GoogleCredentials library to retrieve the default application credential](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#howtheywork).

> 1. The environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is checked. If this variable is specified it should point to a file that
>      defines the credentials. The simplest way to get a credential for this
>      purpose is to create a service account using the [Google Developers
>      Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) in the section **APIs
>      & Auth**, in the sub-section **Credentials**. Create a service account
>      or choose an existing one and select **Generate new JSON key**. Set
>      the environment variable to the path of the JSON file downloaded.
> 2. If you have installed the Google Cloud SDK on your machine and have run the command `gcloud auth login`, your identity can be used as
>      a proxy to test code calling APIs from that machine.
> 3. If you are running in Google App Engine production, the built-in service account associated with the application will be used.
> 4. If you are running in Google Compute Engine production, the built-in service account associated with the virtual machine instance
>      will be used.
> 5. If none of these conditions is true, an error will occur.

It looks like option #2 is probably easiest for you (run `gcloud auth login` to have your code use your Google account for authentication when run locally), but you could also do #1.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with GAE's PHP dev server and had the same issue with the AppIdentity service not working correctly. In PHP you can get around this by setting the `$_SERVER['APPLICATION_ID']` to `dev~yourapplicationid`. I am sure there must be a way to do the same in Java, you just need to prepend `dev~` to the start of your application ID to work with the dev environment.